# Get all permutations of a List(Of List(Of String)) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, iteration, permutation

I have an idea that my problem can be solved using a recursive function but to be honest I can't figure out how to start.

Starting point is a List(Of List(Of String)):

```
Dim Obj As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

I want to retrieve all combinations across all List(Of String) objects.

As example let's assume 2 Lists of Strings containing following values:

```
"a", "b", "c"    
"d", "e"
```

This should result in:

```
"a d"
"a e"
"b d"
"b e"
"c d"
"c e"
```

Final result could also be returned in form of a List(Of String).

I guess that implementing a resursive function may work but I have no idea how to implement:

```
Function createPermutations(ByVal Obj As List(Of List(Of String))) As List(Of String)

    Dim Result As New List(Of String)

    ...
    Result = createPermutations(...)
    ...

    Return Result

End Function
```

Comment: Where to start is where you always start, i.e. work out the logic first and then write code to implement that logic. If you can't do what you want to do with pen and paper, you should not be trying to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Obj As New List(Of List(Of String))

    Dim x As New List(Of String)
    x.Add("a")
    x.Add("b")
    x.Add("c")

    Dim y As New List(Of String)
    y.Add("d")
    y.Add("e")

    Obj.Add(x)
    Obj.Add(y)

    For Each outputString As String In createPermutations(0, Obj)
        System.Console.WriteLine(outputString)
    Next

End Sub

Function createPermutations(level As Integer, listOfLists As List(Of List(Of String)))
    Dim retval As New List(Of String)

    If (level = listOfLists.Count) Then
        retval.Add("")
        Return retval
    End If

    For Each y As String In listOfLists(level)
        For Each x2 As String In createPermutations(level + 1, listOfLists)
            retval.Add(y + " " + x2)
        Next
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using two loop’s an inner and outer like this,

```
Function createPermutations(ByVal Obj As List(Of List(Of String))) As List(Of String)

        Dim Result As New List(Of String)

        Dim list_1 As New List(Of String)
        Dim list_2 As New List(Of String)


        For Each itemL1 In list_1
            For Each itemL2 In list_2
                Result.Add(itemL1 & " " & itemL2)

            Next

        Next
    

        Return Result

    End Function
```

Comment: What if there are more than two lists?  A `List(Of List(Of String))` could hold any number of lists...

Comment: That doesn't seem very versatile.  =/  You'd have to manually change your code based on the input!?

Comment: Exactly, having only two Lists I could hard code it but I do not know the number of Lists in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive solution that can handle any number of sets, where each set has a variable number of elements:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input As New List(Of List(Of String)) From {
        New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c"},
        New List(Of String) From {"d", "e"},
        New List(Of String) From {"f", "g", "h", "i"}
    }

    For Each combination In CartesianProducts(input)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", combination))
    Next

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Iterator Function CartesianProducts(ByVal setList As List(Of List(Of String))) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String))
    Dim curIndex(setList.Count - 1) As Integer ' tells which item is currently being used from each set
    Dim setSizes = setList.Select(Function(curSet) curSet.Count) ' tells the number of items in each set
    Dim numCombinations As Integer = setSizes.Aggregate(Function(a, b) a * b) ' alls the sizes multiplied together

    For i As Integer = 1 To numCombinations
        ' return the current combination by gathering all the elements from each set using "curIndex"
        Yield Enumerable.Range(0, curIndex.Count).Select(Function(x) setList(x)(curIndex(x)))

        ' working backwards, increment the index in each slot
        ' if the new number equals the set size, reset to zero ...
        ' ...and let the loop continue, which will increment the index to the left
        ' if the new number was less than size for that set, simply exit the loop as you're done
        For j As Integer = curIndex.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            curIndex(j) = curIndex(j) + 1
            If curIndex(j) = setSizes(j) Then
                curIndex(j) = 0
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Output:

```
a,d,f
a,d,g
a,d,h
a,d,i
a,e,f
a,e,g
a,e,h
a,e,i
b,d,f
b,d,g
b,d,h
b,d,i
b,e,f
b,e,g
b,e,h
b,e,i
c,d,f
c,d,g
c,d,h
c,d,i
c,e,f
c,e,g
c,e,h
c,e,i
Press Enter to quit...
```

Here's a visual representation of what the `curIndex` array is doing:

```
[ 0,0,0 ]
[ 0,0,1 ]
[ 0,0,2 ]
[ 0,0,3 ]
[ 0,1,0 ]
[ 0,1,1 ]
[ 0,1,2 ]
[ 0,1,3 ]
[ 1,0,0 ]
[ 1,0,1 ]
[ 1,0,2 ]
[ 1,0,3 ]
[ 1,1,0 ]
[ 1,1,1 ]
[ 1,1,2 ]
[ 1,1,3 ]
[ 2,0,0 ]
[ 2,0,1 ]
[ 2,0,2 ]
[ 2,0,3 ]
[ 2,1,0 ]
[ 2,1,1 ]
[ 2,1,2 ]
[ 2,1,3 ]
```